# Upgrading OpenLayers project to new OpenLayers version

Tags: openlayers, upgrade, ol-ext

I have a very complex project made with OpenLayers 6.15.1 integrated with the ol-ext library, I would like to switch to the latest version of OpenLayers which is currently 8.0.0

I would like to do this upgrade to align and to allow the project not to age.

Do I simply load the latest version of OpenLayers and start reading the error logs in the console and one by one go to fix them?

Comment: You will need ol-ext version 4 or later to work with OpenLayers version 7 or later.  Read the OpenLayers upgrade notes https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/changelog/upgrade-notes.md for any compatibility issues with your code.  ol-ext worked with version 7, so far no compatibility issues with version 8 have been reported,

Comment: Thanks Mike, is there a way to not rewrite my code and use the old ol6 classes like "new ol.layer.Vector" or do I have to rewrite everything with the new ol8 classes like "new VectorLayer"?

Comment: You can use the old syntax if you use the cdn versions of ol.js and ol.css from https://openlayers.org/download/